# NativeScript change the outDir of the transpiled code

Tags: angular, webpack, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I don't like the `js` files being generated next to my `ts`/`ng` files , it's so annoying , so I was trying to put the `compiled/transpiled` `js` files outside the `app` directory, as any `Angular` app.

what I did is :

I added `outDir` to the `compilerOptions` inside the `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./compiled/",
....
```

and changed the `main` `entrypoint` inside `app/package.json`

```
{
  "android": {
    "v8Flags": "--expose_gc"
  },
  "main": "./compiled/main.js",
```

by doing so the app crashes since it can't find the `main.js`...

what is the correct way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

after searching for a long time , I found this :-

using Visual Studio code settings for hiding files.

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
         "**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts"},
         "**/*.map": true       
    }    
}
```

it works in my case , but what if I'm using a different IDE/Editor , hopefully there is better solution